# Bootstrap's dropdown buttons not on the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in my code here, but it's this or CSS related. I'm not sure what CSS setting this would be, but here is my navbar section of my html code.

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      TTT Stats
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Scoreboards</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=tttkills">Total TTT Kills</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=tttdeaths">Total TTT Deaths</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=traitorkills">TTT kills as a traitor</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=traitorskilled">Traitors killed as an innocent/detective</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown2">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
      Other
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=playtime">Time Tracker</a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=phkills">Total Prophunt Kills</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

(If anyone is wondering about the names, its for a garry's mod TTT server)

With that code, here is what the complete navbar looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8OWT.png

I would want the two dropdown buttons side by side on that navbar. Now when they are like that, this leads into my next question tied into this. How do you work bootstrap's dropdown CSS if you have more than one button?

This is what I have in my css at the bottom to align the dropdown by the button, so that it is centered correctly below the button and not way over stuck to the left.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  right: 68%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

If there is more than one button, it still centers all buttons to that point on the page. How do I edit their positions individually?

Comment: your second question should be fixed by adding a class called `dropdown` along with `dropdown2` since bootstrap's css won't understand that it's a dropdown.

Comment: Adding those classes seemed to bring me back to square one, actually. With the buttons stacked on eachother and the menus opening at the bottom of the screen. Not sure why, but it seems to work better with no classes defined as dropdown. Interestingly enough, I'm still going to be working on this for a while as it's still completely broken. My two pictures posted in a comment below show what it looks like now for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add btn-group class

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Scoreboards</a>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            TTT Stats <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=tttkills">Total TTT Kills</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=tttdeaths">Total TTT Deaths</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=traitorkills">TTT kills as a traitor</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=traitorskilled">Traitors killed as an innocent/detective</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group dropdown2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Other <span class="caret"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=playtime">Time Tracker</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="index.php?page=phkills">Total Prophunt Kills</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: This fixed it entirely, and everything is working great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question,
you can place your dropdowns inside a structure like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- markup for dropdown 1 --> </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"> <!-- markup for dropdown 2 --> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can use `col` classes like these to make the layout of your page using bootstrap's grid system.
To learn more about them, visit:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thank you, I put them in that structure and that actually fixed my issue of the dropdown menus appearing below the correct one too, although now I just need to position the buttons. Here is what they look like now: http://i.imgur.com/BKtcRRp.png and while we're at it for some reason that voided any css size settings, so now text is going out of boxes: http://i.imgur.com/PCYYN4V.png I believe I can find a fix to this, but thank you so far for solving my html-side of it. edit: Also just noticed that when clicking on the ttt stats dropdown, it appears below the title, so the title may be related.